# Amcharts5 - Error You cannot have multiple Roots on the same DOM node - React 17

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts5

I want to create a chart with amcharts5 in my react app.

I instantiate a root element of amcharts5 in a component that I import in my app component. I get the following error

```
You cannot have multiple Roots in the same DOM node
```

Here's my version:

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
"@amcharts/amcharts5": "^5.1.1"
```

Here's my code:

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import * as am5 from '@amcharts/amcharts5'

export default function AmCharts5() {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let root = am5.Root.new('chartdiv')

    // root.current = root
    // here is a second Error : Property 'current' does not exist on type 'Root'


    return () => {
      root.dispose()
    }
  }, [])

  return <div id="chartdiv" style={{ width: '100%', height: '500px' }}></div>
}
```

Comment: I just recreated your question in this sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-nash-6ks15?file=/src/App.js) and it isn't giving me that error. You might want to check outside of this component, as this error tends to come up when nodes are rendered multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error, when I created second root element for my chart legend, but forgot to add the dispose method for this root element in useEffect return function.
So in my case I solve this error by adding second dispose method in useEffect return function.

In my case useEffect has dependence on some data, and when I change it, useEffect runs again, and try to create second root element with the same name. And at after first render when I change someVar I have this error.

before:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const root = am5.Root.new("chart-pop");
    // ... some code

    const legendRoot = am5.Root.new("legend-div");
    // ... some code

    return () => root.dispose();
}, [someVar]);
```

After:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const root = am5.Root.new("chart-pop");
    // ... some code

    const legendRoot = am5.Root.new("legend-div");
    // ... some code

    return () => {root.dispose(); legendRoot.dispose();};
}, [someVar]);
```

Answer (score 3):

A correct and simple way to fix this error is following the [doc](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/root-element/) from AmCharts5 in the section 'Disposing'. Just put this code before your `am5.ready(function() {...}` and replace your divId =):

```
am5.array.each(am5.registry.rootElements, 
   function(root) {
      if (root.dom.id == divId) {
         root.dispose();
      }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add dynamic id prop on chart component and use that in `am5.Root.new(${props.id})` and add `id={props.id}` in return div that related to amchart.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is save root in a global object and before create chart check if exist the chart, dispose that chart then create again.

```
 var MyGlobalObject={}

 function CrateMyChart(IdDivForDrawChart){
    
    if(MyGlobalObject[IdDivForDrawChart]){   //check if exist chart dispose that
                  MyGlobalObject[IdDivForDrawChart].dispose()
             }

    var  root = am5.Root.new("IdDivForDrawChart");
     // ... some code

     MyGlobalObject[IdDivForDrawChart]=root     // store chart in global object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to create another graph after one exists.
Maybe this was by mistake or you have coded it that way.

Solution:

1. Store your root in a global variable
2. Check if root exists before setting the new root variable

```
if(!!root) root.dispose()

am5.Root.new("id or variable(if in vue or any framework)")`
```